# Prevent users from using an action more than once per object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an application for students on Rails. The application has a series of tests (multiple choice questions, fill-in the blank, ect.). To run a test, a user creates a new "test" object from the index view with a single column, "score." "Score" is set to 0 initially.

The create action then forwards to an action named "question1," passing the new "test" object. The user is presented with a question in the new view and a way to send their answer to the controller through a form. If their response matches the response listed in the controller, the test object that was passed to the "question1" action has it's "score" attribute increased by 1. If the user does not answer correctly, the score attribute is not increased. Either way, when an answer is passed to the controller, the user is presented with a button that allows them to move to the next action, "question2." The submit button on the form (which is really an update button for the "test" object) disappears, and the user is forced to proceed to the next action. It is the only option.

This process continues until they reach the final page which presents them with their total score. Not very complicated. The "test" object basically follows the user through the different views/actions until they get to the final view that gives them thier score.

MY QUESTION: This system is flawed! If a user uses the back arrow in the browser, they can re-take questions. They can even answer the same question multiple times, driving up their score. Is there a way to prevent my "test" object from using it's actions more than once? If each object could somehow be limited to using each question action in the controller once, this could be solved. Here is an example of one of my question actions in the tests_controller.rb:

```
def question1 
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    correct_answer = "<p>"
    user_answer = params[:answer]
    if user_answer == correct_answer
        flash.now[:success] = "That is correct!"
        new_score = @test.score += 1
        @test.update(score: new_score)
    elsif params[:answer].present? && params[:answer] != correct_answer
        flash.now[:danger] = "Wrong answer." 
    end
end
```

Here is the corresponding view:

```
        <%= form_tag question1_path(@test), method: :get do %>
            <h5>1. How do you write an opening paragraph tag in HTML?</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= text_area_tag :answer, params[:answer], class: 'form-control'%>
            </div>
            <% if !flash[:success] && !flash[:danger] %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <% if flash[:success] || flash[:danger] %>
            <%= link_to "Next Question", question2_path(@test), class:"btn btn-success pull-right" %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Can't you just track which questions have been answered?

Comment: You can use headers pragma, cache control and expires to invalidate a page imidiadly.  This works with most browsers.  To ensure your policy and deal with tampered data,  you have to track answered questions.

Comment: Is there an article somewhere that discusses this?